# useEffect + watch does not seem to filter the changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I try to use [watch hook](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch) to watch a variable changes - `city`. However, I would like that only `city` variable produces the effect, not all the form (say, `name` should not log anything): [see the sample on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/watch-filter?file=App.tsx):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

export default function App() {
  const { watch, register } = useForm({
    mode: 'all',
    reValidateMode: 'onBlur',
  });

  const cityValue = watch('city', 'my city');
  const nameValue = watch('name', 'my name');

  // Will console the changes
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = watch((value, { name, type }) =>
      console.log(value, name, type)
    );
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, [cityValue]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Start editing & look at the console how values changes :</p>
      <input value={cityValue} {...register('city')} />
      <label>{cityValue}</label> <br />
      <input value={nameValue} {...register('name')} />
      <label>{nameValue}</label> <br />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Why does the `[cityValue]` filter in the `useEffect` not work?

It seem that the `useEffect` with `[cityValue]` above would be same as `useEffect` with `[]`...

Answer (score 0):

The condition on `useEffect` only states under which circumstances to re-run the effect, it has no effect on the values inside the effect. The `watch` call inside your effect applies to all watches it seems, and registers a change-listener for all of them. It also does so every time the city value changes, which you probably don't want.

I think what you want is just:

```
  React.useEffect(() => console.log(cityValue), [cityValue]);
```

Comment: so, there is no way to `watch` only a variable, not all of them? I mean the line with subscription –

Comment: yes there is and you already are. If I'm reading the documentation right then these two things are alternatives. Either you use the `watch('city', ..)` notation, OR you use the callback/subscription syntax. I don't think there is much of a point in using both at the same time.

Comment: if I *don't* use subscription, I can't track changes, if I *do* use subscription, I can't track just one if the fields...

Comment: finally, only sith watch, there is NOK, I should combine them like here https://stackblitz.com/edit/watch-filter-mygp2j?file=App.tsx,index.tsx

Comment: what's wrong with my answer? It gives you exactly what you need, no? Just tracking city value changes.